# nested gridview no data, if the parent gridview get populated on (where = querystring) need help here

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested

the question is as above.
I have a parent gridview that will get populated by taking the query string.
however, the child gridview (nested) then will not be populated. i dont understand why too. 
any help?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="447px">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" ReadOnly="True" 
                 SortExpression="QuestionID" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="SurveyID" HeaderText="SurveyID" 
                 SortExpression="SurveyID" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionTitle" HeaderText="QuestionTitle" 
                 SortExpression="QuestionTitle" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerType" HeaderText="AnswerType" 
                 SortExpression="AnswerType" />
             <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                         BorderStyle="Solid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerValue" HeaderText="AnswerValue" 
                                 SortExpression="AnswerValue" />
                         </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Question] WHERE ([SurveyID] = @SurveyID)">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SurveyID" QueryStringField="sid" 
                 Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>

  </div>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 


     SelectCommand="SELECT AnswerValue FROM Results WHERE (QuestionID = @QuestionID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add `HiddenField` into an ItemTemplate of GridView1 and bind it with `QuestionID`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   ...
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                            Value='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                BorderStyle="Solid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerValue" HeaderText="AnswerValue" 
                   SortExpression="AnswerValue" />
                </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and use ControlParameter to compare QuestionID with SqlDataSource2.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT AnswerValue FROM Results WHERE (QuestionID = @QuestionID)">
     <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="QuestionID" 
                                    PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: im showing the QuestionID, so i dont have to make it as hiddenfield.

Comment: it gives me this error : DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.

Comment: @MarlinusYapi - You have to re-configure both these data source control.